# Transforming XML to create Parent-Child relation, using XSLT (loading data into AccessDB

Tags: xml, vba, macos, ms-access, xslt

I have a source XML as mentioned below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:DATA xmlns:soap-env="*****" xmlns:tns="****" xmlns:nxsd="*****"><tns:Information><tns:tenantId>PARENT_STRING1</tns:tenantId><tns:userSessionId>PARENT_STRING2</tns:userSessionId><tns:startTime>PARENT_STRING3</tns:startTime><tns:endTime>PARENT_STRING4</tns:endTime><tns:duration>PARENT_STRING5</tns:duration><tns:userActions><tns:name>CHILD_STRING1</tns:name><tns:domain>CHILD_STRING2</tns:domain>    <tns:targetUrl>CHILD_STRING3</tns:targetUrl><tns:type>CHILD_STRING4</tns:type>... etc</tns:userActions>....etc</tns:Information></tns:DATA>
```

And I want to convert this into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:DATA xmlns:soap-env="*****" xmlns:tns="****" xmlns:nxsd="*****"><tns:Information><tns:tenantId>PARENT_STRING1</tns:tenantId><tns:userSessionId>PARENT_STRING2</tns:userSessionId><tns:startTime>PARENT_STRING3</tns:startTime><tns:endTime>PARENT_STRING4</tns:endTime><tns:duration>PARENT_STRING5</tns:duration><tns:userActions><tns:userSessionId>PARENT_STRING2</tns:userSessionId><tns:startTime>PARENT_STRING3</tns:startTime><tns:endTime>PARENT_STRING4</tns:endTime><tns:duration>PARENT_STRING5</tns:duration><tns:name>CHILD_STRING1</tns:name><tns:domain>CHILD_STRING2</tns:domain><tns:targetUrl>CHILD_STRING3</tns:targetUrl><tns:type>CHILD_STRING4</tns:type>... etc</tns:userActions>....etc</tns:Information></tns:DATA>
```

I am using the XSLT as mentioned below,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tns="http://www.esa.int/tns/sentinel-1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:Information">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:userActions">
    <tns:userActions>
        <tns:tenantId><xsl:value-of select="../tns:tenantId"/></tns:tenantId>
        <tns:ParentStartTime><xsl:value-of select="../tns:startTime"/></tns:ParentStartTime>
        <tns:ParentEndTime><xsl:value-of select="../tns:endTime"/></tns:ParentEndTime>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </tns:userActions>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT is not working and XML is not converting into my expected format. Can you please highlight what I am missing here...???

Thanks a lot.!

My VBA code part to do the same is mentioned below,

```
  ' LOAD XML SOURCE
  'xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile
  xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

  If (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Error loading source document: " & xmlDoc.parseError.reason)
    Exit Sub
    Else
  If (xslDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Error loading stylesheet document: " & xslDoc.parseError.reason)
    Exit Sub
    Else
     ' Do the transform.
     xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
     newDoc.Save "C:\temp\temp.xml"
     Application.ImportXML "C:\temp\temp.xml", acAppendData
     strFile = Dir()
  End If
  End If

  ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
  'xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

  'newDoc.Save "C:\temp\temp.xml"

  ' APPEND TO TABLES
  ' Application.ImportXML "C:\temp\temp.xml", acAppendData
  ' strFile = Dir()
```

Comment: What does not working mean apart from not transforming as expected. Are there any error messages?

Comment: No errors.. But the temp.xml which I am creating through Transform is just similar to the original file.. No change in that and hence the output is not what I expect...

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT stylesheet works fine, you just need to remove the template for `tns:Information`.

I had to fix the namespaces, you can't just replace them with asterisks.

Check the fiddle here: http://xsltransform.net/bEJaogP